# Round-robin algorithm in OCaml

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, round-robin

This is the followup question of [What's the grouping plan so that every two people are grouped together just once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312670/whats-the-grouping-plan-so-that-every-two-people-are-grouped-together-just-once)

Basically, I implemented the [Round robin algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm).

---

By the algorithm, it can generate pairs list where each possible pair of elements are grouped together exactly once.

For example, we have `a, b, c, d`, then

On first day, we do

`a` `b`
`c d`

Then we group like [(a,c);(b,d)].

Then we round it clockwise like

`a` `c`
`d b`

Then we group like [(a,d);(c,b)].

Then we round it clockwise like

`a` `d`
`b c`

Then we group like [(a,b);(d,c)].

(Note, `a` is fixed all the time.)

Finally I can get

[(a,c);(b,d)]
[(a,d);(c,b)]
[(a,b);(d,c)]

---

Here are the ocaml code:

```
let split = List.fold_left (fun (l1, l2) x -> (l2, x::l1)) ([], []) 

let round l1 l2 =
  match List.rev l1, l2 with
    | _, [] | [], _ -> raise Cant_round
    | hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2 ->
      hd2::(List.rev tl1), List.rev (hd1::List.rev tl2)

let rec robin fixed stopper acc = function
  | _, [] | [], _ -> raise Cant_robin
  | l1, (hd2::tl2 as l2) -> 
    if hd2 = stopper then acc
    else robin fixed stopper ((List.combine (fixed::l1) l2)::acc) (round l1 l2)

let round_robin = function
  | [] | _::[] -> raise Cant_round_robin
  | hd::tl ->
    let l1, l2 =  in
    match split tl with 
      | _, [] -> raise Cant_round_robin
      | l1, (hd2::_ as l2) -> 
    robin hd hd2 ((List.combine (hd::l1) l2)::[]) (round l1 l2)
```

The code is quite straight forward following the algorithm. **Is there a better implmentation?**

Comment: IDK if it helps, but here's a good description of what the solution might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658727/how-can-i-generate-a-round-robin-tournament-in-php-and-mysql

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan thanks, but that implementation is using array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let round_robin ~nplayers ~round i =
  (* only works for an even number of players *)
  assert (nplayers mod 2 = 0);
  assert (0 <= round && round < nplayers - 1);
  (* i is the position of a match,
     at each round there are nplayers/2 matches *)
  assert (0 <= i && i < nplayers / 2);
  let last = nplayers - 1 in
  let player pos =
    if pos = last then last
    else (pos + round) mod last
  in
  (player i, player (last - i))

let all_matches nplayers =
  Array.init (nplayers - 1) (fun round ->
    Array.init (nplayers / 2) (fun i ->
      round_robin ~nplayers ~round i))

let _ = all_matches 6;;
(**
[|[|(0, 5); (1, 4); (2, 3)|];
  [|(1, 5); (2, 0); (3, 4)|];
  [|(2, 5); (3, 1); (4, 0)|];
  [|(3, 5); (4, 2); (0, 1)|];
  [|(4, 5); (0, 3); (1, 2)|]|]
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to compute the clockwise rotation by operating over actual data. You can represent it as picking indices in a fixed array (of things you rotate): after rotating the array `t` `r` times, the element at index `i` in the rotated array will be at index `i+r` in the original array, in fact `(i+r) mod (Array.length t)` to have wrap-around.

With this idea you could compute pairing without moving data around, simply incrementing a counter representing the number of rotations performed so far. In fact, you could probably even come up with a purely numerical solution that does not create any data structure (the array of things-to-rotate), and reasons on the various indices to apply this reasoning.

Comment: This way will involve array, but what's the better way for pure functional in ocaml?

Comment: Arrays can be purely functional if you don't mutate them.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been answered, but the correct answer is in an imperative way.

I finally found the following way to deal with round-robin algorithm simpler in functional way.

```
let round l1 l2 = let move = List.hd l2 in move::l1, (List.tl l2)@[move]

let combine m l1 l2 =
  let rec comb i acc = function
    |[], _ | _, [] -> acc
    |_ when i >= m -> acc
    |hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2 -> comb (i+1) ((hd1,hd2)::acc) (tl1,tl2)
  in
  comb 0 [] (l1,l2)

let round_robin l =
  let fix = List.hd l in
  let half = (List.length l)/2 in
  List.fold_left (
      fun (acc, (l1, l2)) _ -> (combine half (fix::l1) l2)::acc, round l1 l2
    ) ([], (List.tl l, List.rev l)) l |> fst |> List.tl
```